# How to store special characters from Twitter API into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to properly store Tweets into a MySQL database. A.o, the Twitter Search API returns the following:

```
from_user_name":"Daniel Salas Jim\u00e9nez"
```

As can be seen from the [profile page](https://twitter.com/dansalasjmz), this translates into Daniel Salas Jiménez. My `utf8_general_ci` encoded database, however, stores this as Daniel Salas JimÃ©nez. Notice that nor `\u00e9` or `é` is stored, but `Ã©`. I have no way of ever concerting this back into `é`.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong in storing Twitter data? How can I store this users username so that I can read it from MySQL properly, being `Daniel Salas Jiménez`?

Comment: Another UTF8 encoding duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all because of the charset problem. You are trying to see it in charset="UTF-8" where as the twitter charset is charset="iso-8859-1" Your mysql based database it saving it correctly but not displaying it correct , So when you need that to be displayed it on some page use the  charset="iso-8859-1" in header

example

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: I'm confused. If I retrieve the seemingly badly-formatted data (`JimÃ©nez`) from MySQL, the name also displays correctly when using `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`. Why is this and how can I be sure exactly WHAT is being stored in MySQL (I'm using PHPMyAdmin to view the database)?

Comment: i think you should just use charset="iso-8859-1" and forget all. what so ever you will crawl or fetch from twitter it is no way gonna change when you will be saving it to database, there might be display related problems which will get sorted with ISO. UTF is generally required when we have to use other language then English. It's just an idea maybe someone can come up with something more better.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is utf_unicode_ci, you can use this:

[utf8_decode() PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php)
[utf8_encode() PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php)